# Google maps-how does the zoom in work for determining relative importance of cities?

Tags: google-maps

Initially when google displays the tiles on google map, you see just the continents.

On further zoom level, you start seeing cities.
First the important cities appear, then on further zoom less important ones and then streets etc.

I understand the concept of google tiles and zoom levels.
However what I would like to know is how is it decided at what zoom level, which are the important cities to show?
Say for switzerland, at zoom level 6 you can see Zurich,Basel
At zoom level 7 Lucern, Berm, St. Gallen appear.

I used the following visualiser: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

How is the relative importance of these cities decided to show up on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your question was down-voted, as it's a curious question. However I think only a Google Maps employee could provide a truly correct answer, the rest of us would just be guessing.

It will come down to whatever conditions/rules the Google cartographers used to render tiles for the various zoom levels. Like, at zoom=Z, all capital cities are shown, in addition to any cities with population above X. Then at zoom=Z+1, lesser cities with a population between Xmax and Xmin range are added, with a weaker font styling. Then at Z+2, same, but for a new set of population ranges.

..and it's worth considering that you *will* have a greater density of high-population cities along the coastal areas, but in the continental interiors, you might need to relax your rules somewhat in order to show any cities at all!

While I bet most cartographers settle for a one-size-fits-all set of rules, I suspect Google's carto rules are extremely complex. I would not be shocked--at all--to learn that Google had per-tile overrides with additional spatial filters ..or even paid advertising filters that trump their more generic styles that render the rest of the map.

For example, let's say a midwest USA city wants to increase its tourism or its prominence, etc. ..maybe they pay Google for advertising, so Google subtly increases their presence in the map.

I'm not sure if this is an example of this or not, but [both Branson, MO, USA and Fayetteville, AR, USA appear at zoom=6](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.7404353,-91.0814481,6z), while the state capital of Arkansas (Little Rock) does not! Now, Branson is a tourism destination, and Fayetteville is ..well, "progressive and on the move" ..or something. But check this out--not only is Little Rock the capital of Arkansas, but it's population is 120,000 *more* than Fayetteville, AND multiple interstates flow through it! .....I can't imagine a sensible reason for promoting Branson and Fayetteville over the state capital of Arkansas unless some form of advertising money is the reason itself. Someone might be quick to say "well, Little Rock is right in the middle of the state, so that would compete with the label for Arkansas on the map." However, look over at Oklahoma ([again at z=6](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.1457837,-90.2563114,6z)). Oklahoma City is the capital of Oklahoma, and the state name label is displayed a little to the north to make room for both labels on the map ..FWIW OKC's population is > 600000, which may be the dominating cartographic rule for z=6. But that returns me to the question, why would Brason and Fayetteville, then, be promoted at this level?

So as you can see there is a fundamental answer to your question: Rules and Filters are used to define styles for what map features are rendered for any given zoom level. But there may be very complex cases and style overrides that occur for reasons that we can only speculate about.